# How can I fix this VS Code / .NET Core SDK issue?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, visual-studio-code, sdk, dotnet

When starting VSCode (Visual Studio Code) I'm receiving the following error:

[image: .NET Core SDK Error]

When I search for my installed version in Terminal:

```
computer@computeruser-wild-cpu:~$ dotnet --version
3.1.100
```

Do I need to change versions. or do something with VS?

The current website:

[image]

Comment: Might I add, VS and running code works fine.   
Running on Ubuntu 18.04.  
According to this website only Microsoft version of VS supports debugging
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Microsoft-.NET-Core-Debugger-licensing-and-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Code
***Can this be confirmed?***